# Adding multiple pods

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

Hello quick question,

I am working on an xcode project and originally added the Firebase pod. However, as I am building the project I want to add another pod from another organization. Do I need to do an additional '''pod init'''? or can I just add the new pod functionality into the same pod to have have one podfile?

Thank You.

Comment: No need to run `Pod init` again, just add your all the new pods into your podfile and run 'pod install'

Answer (score 1):

The `pod init` command creates a new Podfile if it does not already exist, but in your case you already seem to have a Podfile in the project. Simply add a new pod as follows:

```
target mApp do
    ...

    # Add more pods ...
    pod 'Alamofire'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON'

    ...
end
```

Run `pod install` command to install new pods.